# How can I run a Snappy / ubuntu-core image with LXD

Tags: lxc, ubuntu-core

I would like to run Ubuntu Snappy in an LXC container.

There isn't an existing snappy image at the default https://images.linuxcontainers.org repo, but I was wondering if this is something others have tried and what I would need to get started.

For context, I am interested in running snappy in a system container (via lxd on the cli for local dev, and openstack for shared environments) to act as a host os for running application containers with Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now supported:
   `lxc launch images:ubuntu-core/16/amd64 ubuntu-core`

Credit @stgraber

https://stgraber.org/2017/01/31/ubuntu-core-in-lxd-containers/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: results in: `error: not found (not a fingerprint, partial fingerprint (first 12 chars) or valid alias)` It seems the tag name is now ubuntu-core/16/amd64

Answer (score 3):

The LXD snappy package is not yet currently available as a general release image for LXC. What is however availble is a snap for testing LXD on snappy - stgraber has posted about this here:

https://plus.google.com/+St%C3%A9phaneGraber/posts/aX6vogzEQ1X

relevant bits:

```
A binary for amd64 can be downloaded at:
    https://dl.stgraber.org/lxd_0.11-git0_amd64.snap

Then installed with:
    snappy-remote --url=ssh://localhost:8022 install lxd_0.11-git0_amd64.snap
```

But this only helps you get started running other containers on snappy, not with loading snappy in LXD.

A good place to start the dialogue about what you would like to do would be the ubuntu mailing lists for LXD, or perhaps file a bug against the LXD project requesting a snappy image be published for consumption, where the team can then build an image, or request  CPC build one.

Anything beyond that will be an exercise in manually building the LXC rootfs and containerizing it. YMMV

Answer (score 2):

Due to kernel restrictions with regard to apparmor and unprivileged squashfs, both of which are required for Ubuntu Core's security model, it's not currently feasible to run snappy inside a LXD or LXC container.

It's something we'd definitely like to have soon but it seems unlikely that we'll achieve it for Ubuntu 16.04, nor is it on our roadmap for now.